# Delete category and related posts from front end

Tags: wordpress, frontend, categories

I'm not even sure if this is possible. I want to be able to delete a category and any posts that are in that category - from the front end.

I have this code which spits out all the categories just fine:

```
<?php
$categories = get_categories('exclude=1&order=ASC');
foreach ($categories as $cat) { 
$posts = new WP_Query( array('post_type' => 'post', 'showposts' => -1, 'post_status' =>     array('trash', 'publish'), 'cat' => $cat->cat_ID));
?>

<div>
<h2><a href="<?php echo $cat->category_nicename; ?>"><?php echo $cat->cat_name; ?></a>    </h2>
<p><?php echo $cat->category_description; ?></p>

<a href="">click here to delete this category and all task</a>

</div>
<?php }
?>
```

If this is not possible, I'll settle for deleting just the category alone if that's all that can be done.

Any suggestions would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Sorted it out myself. Basically when clicking the delete anchor I'm targeting a hidden iframe. The URL for that page and even the delete anchors are only accessible to admins anyway so I don't see any security implications.